# Is there a performance penalty using in-place models/families in a large Revit project

Tags: cad, revit

*(I'm quite new at Revit so apologies if my concepts are a bit inaccurate)*

I have heard using, in-place models in Revit projects is poor practice since it can slow down a large project. However I noticed Revit also organising inplace models lumping them with the rest of the families. So my question is:

Is there really any performance penalty/benefit to be had by inserting families from an external file as opposed to creating inplace models in a Revit project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'In-Place' families embeds many of the project parameters/materials/object styles normally not present in a family which does have impact on performance and file size.

More importantly, there is no way to convert an 'In-Place' Family to a 'Loadable' Family so It is a 1 use only affair.

We tend to restrict In Place families to unique bench tops and unique landscape bits that won't be reused. I would rather spend a little more time on a parametric (changeable) family that can be reused than a quick In Place mock up.